# Matching multi-language (latin extended) characters in lua

Tags: lua, character-encoding, pattern-matching

I'm unable to find a way to match all extended alphabet characters without doing so explicitly. For example, matching the tag `språk`.

```lua
tag = "språk"
tag:match([[%w+]])
```

This doesn't work because `å` is not contained within `%w`. This can be matched with `tag:match([[[%wå]+]])`, but then you have to explicitly add all special.

One can also extend the range. This works `tag:match([[[a-å]+]])`, but I'm not 100% clear on why, or at least not where that range actually covers in the character table.

So what is the correct way to match a range that includes all ascii plus all latin extended?

---

The best solution I've come up with so far is:

```lua
tag = "språk"
tag:match([[[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ]+]])
```

But I'm still unsure if that is completely correct, and it would be ideal if there is a shortcut class for this I'm simply overlooking.

Comment: 1. This depends on which charset your file is saved in. 2. It's almost impossible to cover all latin extended with lua's pattern, note there are more than 10 different kinds of latin extended in Unicode, and a lot of characters are multibyte.

Comment: Does `[^%p%s]` (everything except space+punctuation) work for your use-case?

Comment: Maybe. That is helpful, but actually I need some supported punctuation in the tags that are being matched. That does, nevertheless, match all the letters required but not all characters, and probably far to many otherwise. Essentially, the goal is to match all letter-like characters, plus dashes. And barring some shortcut class I'm unfamiliar with, like `%å` or some such, the `[[À-ÿ]]` seems the most direct.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest how to make a set of some characters from additional Latin letters - 1. By analogy, you can make sets for the necessary sets (Latin Extended A,B,C,D,E).

```
------------------------ just generate set Latin-1 Supplement
local set = ""
for x = 0x80, 0xBF do
    set = set  ..   string.char("0xC3", string.format("0x%x",x) )  
end
print(set)
--------------------------

--- get it from print above
local ex = [[ÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ]]

-- By analogy you can get Extended Latin A:
-- local ext_latin_A = [[ĀāĂăĄąĆćĈĉĊċČčĎďĐđĒēĔĕĖėĘęĚěĜĝĞğĠġĢģĤĥĦħĨĩĪīĬĭĮįİıĲĳĴĵĶķĸĹĺĻļĽľĿŀŁłŃńŅņŇňŉŊŋŌōŎŏŐőŒœŔŕŖŗŘřŚśŜŝŞşŠšŢţŤťŦŧŨũŪūŬŭŮůŰűŲųŴŵŶŷŸŹźŻżŽžſÍ]]

tag = "språk"

print("-----")
print( tag:match("[%w".. ex .."]+") )
```

Comment: Thanks. I suppose this ends up being functionally the same as `[[À-ÿ]]` or `[[Ā-Í]]` respectively?

Comment: These are the letter codes from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1_Supplement and what exactly are the ranges, I can't know how to do according to yours. It can be conditionally divided into Capital `[[À-Þ]]` and Small `[[ß-ÿ]]`

Answer (score 0):

Make your own match function, but:

Take the string and replace all odd letters as å to a. Than match this new string, not the old one.
[Replace Accented Characters in string to standard with LUA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50459102/replace-accented-characters-in-string-to-standard-with-lua)

Comment: But "a" and "å" are different letters.

Comment: I was sure that you need to find the letter independent of accent, so making the string without them and search among clear Latin letters and than, if found, you can return the same from the original string.